# How to expose the users in my classes (model), or list all in my views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I would like to expose the users of Identity framework from ASP.NET Core 2.2 in my classes (model) in order to assign an action to a user that I can select from the list of users.

```
public abstract class Issue
{
    public Guid IssueId { get; set; }
    public IssueType IssueType { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDatePrevision { get; set; }
    public bool IsExtrajudicial { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a reference of users or list of users inside this class.

Comment: Sounds like you should add `public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }`. If that is not helpful (enough), then you need to **[edit]** the question and explain better what you want or where you are stuck, including code samples of what you have tried.

Comment: So what is the exact issue? Is something not working? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achive that by adding a new property like this one:

```
public IEnumerable<IdentityUser> Users {get; set;}
```